# <SKPaymentQueue: 0x281194d90>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to make an in app purchase inside my app but for some reason when i enter my apple ID and my password i'm getting an error on the log and nothing happens on UI. I nedd to upload my app on test flight or something like this to be able to purchase items from my app?. I have added the payment methods and the tax info.

I'm just calling the purchase product method from my view.

**The error:**

```
2021-09-14 19:06:01.857244+0300 iGrow Goals[697:72415] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x2802709f0>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x280ec2610 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The verify credentials call failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x280ec2700 {Error Domain=AMSServerErrorDomain Code=-5000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AMSServerErrorDomain error -5000.)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (AMSServerErrorDomain error -5000.)}}}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}
```

**StoreManager.swift:**

```
//
//  StoreManager.swift
//  iGrow Goals
//
//  Created by George Sepetadelis on 30/8/21.
//

import Foundation
import StoreKit

class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    
    @Published var myProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var request: SKProductsRequest!
    
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    
    func enablePremiumPlan() {
        
    }
    
    func purchaseProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        } else {
            print("User can't make payment.")
        }
    }
    
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
            case .purchased:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                print("payment success")
                transactionState = .purchased
                enablePremiumPlan()
            case .restored:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
                enablePremiumPlan()
            case .failed, .deferred:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .failed
                print("payment failed")
            default:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                print("default")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getProducts(productIDs: [String]) {
        print("Start requesting products ...")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Did receive response")
        
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Request did fail: \(error)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It will only show UI if you tell it to show an bakery or something. You don’t have anything inside your last delegate method where the Fail is reported.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10114/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api

Comment: @loremipsum i need to add something to my app delegate?

Comment: the last method of your `SKProductsRequestDelegate` needs to notify the user of the error

Comment: @loremipsum and how can i dot that?

Comment: That is up to you, an `Alert` would be a basic solution. As. standard practice anywhere you have something that returns an `error` should notify the user or else the user will be left in the dark. Imagine if you didn't have the console, just your device. Think about the user experience.

Comment: @loremipsum Okay, i will do that and i will check what error gives me

Comment: @loremipsum the problem is not the updates on UI but the error, i don't know why i'm getting this error

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652120

Comment: Seems to be a known thing. Go through the videos and sample  I posted earlier on. Many people are having issues and the release notes talk about a few sandbox issues. The RC version of Xcode and iOS 15 just dropped so give those a try

Comment: Also, seems obvious to say but make sure you are using a [sandbox account](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox). Your regular account won't work straight out of Xcode

Comment: "when i enter my apple ID and my password"  What does that mean?  You mean, you are using an actual account running the app on an actual device?

Comment: @ElTomato I singed in with my tester sandbox account and it worked, I have been trying to log in to my regular apple account for so long

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for you to test your app's in-app purchases with an acutal account unless they are already approved by App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a sandbox account when testing in app purchases straight out of Xcode.

Your regular account will work on Test Flight and when in the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox

Comment: Hello again. I added a StoreKit Config file to Xcode, and on simulator or device I get the same error: `<SKPaymentQueue: 0x282a21930>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2826a7fc0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}`

Comment: Same thing happens on physical device (I mentioned that in the above comment). Thanks